# How to import a SpriteFont into MonoGame

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-assets, monogame, spritefont

I'm porting a simple tetris-like XNA app to Android, using Mono For Android and MonoGame; I have followed the suggested steps in [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF0sm5KGPPM) and so far, everything compiles well, and no relevant warnings fire up. However, upon loading the contents, a null parameter exception breaks the program at the point below in my program:

```
protected override void LoadContent() {
    // ...
    _font = Content.Load<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");
    // ... 
}
```

The content root directory is set in the game constructor class:

```
public Game2 (){
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
Content.RootDirectory = "Assets/Content"; // TEST.
//...}
```

And I have tried several combinations, all to no avail.

I have also tried setting the xnb files as Content as well as Android Assets in the Build Action property; having the linked, copied always, copied only if newer... etc.

Either way, my problem is that I don't really understand  *WHY* and *HOW* should I do this. I'm rather new to the platform and to XNA as well, so this may very well be a newbie question, but the truth is after several hours banging my head and fists against the monitor/keyboard I feel stuck and need your help.

Answer (score 0):

MonoGame (2.5.1) throws NotImplementedException in ContentManager.Load for SpriteFont type. Have the same not resolved problem. I'm trying not to use DrawString.

For loading textures in Win32 application I use:

```
Content.RootDirectory = @"../../Content";
var sampleTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sample.png");
```

You even must not add it to solution.

For Andoind (MonoDroid) application you must add "Content" folder to your solution and set "Andtoid Asset" in "Sample.png" properties.

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
var sampleTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sample.png");
```

See also:

http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/360468

http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/267900

Answer (score 0):

I have a [library](https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti) that supports variable-width fonts (generated by [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)) on MonoGame. Unfortunately it is a renderer and so has other code around it. However, the basic idea is very simple. You can take a look at the [loader](https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti/blob/master/Graffiti.Core/Text/BitmapFont.cs) here and the mesh builder (given a string) [here](https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti/blob/master/Graffiti.Core/Text/BitmapText.cs). This builder supports fonts that spread characters across multiple pages, too.

Hope this helps!